# Cannot change the cells value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change rows 2 to 10 in column 4 to 10 but it does not work.

Restriction: `d As Single` must not be changed

```
Sub ua()
    Dim d As Single
    Dim i As Integer

    d = Cells(i, 4)

    For i = 2 To 10
        d = 10
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `range(cells(2, 4), cells(10, 10)) = 10` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @jeeped ys, but i have been given a single typed 'd' . It refers to discount in my assignment. I have another code that will determine the discount of the items and i will use for loop to assign the particular discount to them in another column. So I think d = Cells(i, 4) where the i will change in the loop otherwise the single typed d is useless in my assignment. So i just wonder is that a way to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

Looping through the rows and columns is one option:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim myRow As Long, myCol As Long
    Dim d As Single: d = 10
    For myRow = 2 To 10
        For myCol = 4 To 10
            Worksheets(1).Cells(myRow, myCol) = d
        Next myCol
    Next myRow

End Sub
```

Another one is using the single line solution of @Jeep from the comments -

```
With Workheets(1)
    .Range(.Cells(2, 4), .Cells(10, 10)) = 10
end with
```

Answer (score 2):

Change Sheet name and try:

```
Sub test()

    With Sheet1

        .Range(.Cells(2, 4), .Cells(10, 10)).Value = 10

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @Vityata please review the edit and provide feedback!

Comment: yup, this was the idea. Still the code is quite the same as the one in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You actually doing nothing with your code (you just set a variable and then you loop without any restult on cell values). If you want to change a value in a cell you have to write this in your code. You can change a value in a cell like this:

```
 Cells(3, 2).Value = 2
```

If you want this variable and in a loop you can write the following:

```
For i = 2 to 10
  Cells(3, i).Value = 1000 'Set the value of the cell to 1000
Next i
```